# How to set a flag in splunk using lookup

Tags: lookup, splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to achieve below logic
trying to set a flag called <**adminuser**>  the current user ID is present in the lookup (in the lookup 4 ID is there AAP1 APP2 AAP3)
if adminuser is False, then filter where Requestor in the event is  else do not filter
Only the 4 ids can see the user details. and rest can see only there request.

My XMl code is

index=* sourcetype="testapp" |eval split=split(Requestor, "@"), Requestor=mvindex(split, 0)
| eval "Requested Date" = strftime(_time,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
| Get current user ID = (| rest /services/authentication/current-context splunk_server=local | rename username as Requestor |eval split=split(Requestor, "@"), Requestor=mvindex(split, 0))
| want to use flag  if current user ID is present in lookup
| if adminuser is False, then filter where Requestor in event is  else do not filter
|table "Requested Date" "ID" "Requestor" "MD" "SM"  "SL"  Status

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be used to set a flag

```
| eval adminuser=[ 
    | rest /services/authentication/current-context splunk_server=local 
    | join type=inner username [ | inputlookup adminusers ]
    | stats count
    | eval search=if(count>0,"1","0")
  ]
```

This assumes your lookup contains a single column, called `username`.

Post some event samples if you need further clarification

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Simon Duff 
but the above code is not working it is giving me 0 output
and under the username, we have 4 value AAP1 AAP2 AAP3 AAP4

Comment: You will need to provide examples of your events and confirm your lookup works properly. What does ` I inputlookup adminusers` return